# My django form is showing that data is posted but data isnt being saved to database

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

So my form was working just fine until i played around with my frontend...changing the look of the system. But i dont think this has an effect on my forms but surprisingly all my forms are no longer saving data to the database!!
Some help here guys.
Here is my views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib import messages
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from .forms import *

# Create your views here.
def register(request):
    form = RegistrationForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'User successfully registered!')
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
    return render(request, 'accounts/register.html', {'form': form} )

def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
            username = username.POST['username']
            password = request.POST['password']

            try:
                user = Account.objects.get(username=username)
            except:
                messages.error(request, 'username does not exist')

            user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('home')
            else:
                messages.error(request, 'Invalid username Or Password')
    return render(request, 'accounts/login.html', {} )
```

models.py

```
from distutils.command.upload import upload
import email
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager

class MyAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def _create_user(self, email, username, profile_pic, address, phone_number, car, details, password):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("User must have an email")
        if not username:
            raise ValueError("User must have a username")

        user = self.model(
               email = self.normalize_email(email),
               username = username, profile_pic=profile_pic, address = address,
               phone_number = phone_number, car=car, details=details, password=password
            )   

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user 

    def create_user(self, email, username, profile_pic=None, address=None, phone_number=None, car=None, details=None, password=None):
        return self._create_user(email, username, profile_pic, address, phone_number, car, details, password)

    def create_superuser(self, email, username, password):
        """
        Creates and saves a superuser with the given email, name and password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(email=email,
            username=username,
            password=password,
            
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class Account(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(verbose_name='username', unique=True, max_length=60, null=True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(blank=False, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(verbose_name='address', max_length=200, null=True)
    phone_number = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='phone_number', null=True)
    car = models.CharField(verbose_name='car' , max_length=60, blank=False, null=True)
    details = models.CharField(verbose_name='details',  unique=True, max_length=60, blank=False, null=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last_login', auto_now=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']
    objects = MyAccountManager()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

    @property
    def profile_picURL(self):
        try:
            url = self.profile_pic.url
        except:
            url = ''
        return url

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'static/images')
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from accounts.models import Account, UserProfile





class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'email'}), help_text='Required. Add a valid email address')
    username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'username'}))
    #profile_pict = forms.ImageField()
    address = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'address'}))
    phone_number = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'phone_number'}))
    car = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'car'}))
    details = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'details'}))
    profile_picture = forms.ImageField()


    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ('email', 'username', 'address', 'phone_number', 'car', 'details')


class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('user', 'avatar')

    def clean_avatar(self):
        avatar = self.cleaned_data['avatar']
        return avatar
```

and the template:

```
    {% load static %}
{% include 'others/base.html' %}
{% include 'others/sidebar.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}



<div  class="card"style="margin-top: 58px; margin-left: 300px; margin-right: 20px; height: 45px;">
    <h3 style="text-align: center; color: black;">Register New Drivers</h3>
      <div class="form" style=" height: 600px; padding-top: 60px; padding-left: 50px; background-color: gainsboro;">
        <form  method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}    
            <div class="form-row" >
                <div class="col-md-6 mb-0">
                  {{ form.email|as_crispy_field }}
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 mb-0">
                  {{ form.username|as_crispy_field }}
                </div>
                <!--<div class="col-md-6 mb-0">
                  {{ form.profile_picture|as_crispy_field }}
                </div>-->
                <div class="col-md-12 mb-0">
                  {{ form.address|as_crispy_field }}
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 mb-0">
                  {{ form.phone_number|as_crispy_field }}
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 mb-0">
                  {{ form.car|as_crispy_field }}
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 mb-0">
                  {{ form.details|as_crispy_field }}
                </div>
                <input style="margin-left: 10px;" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" href ="{% url 'home' %}" value="Sign Up">

            </div>
        </form> 
      </div>     
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

I would really appreciate your help...its giving me a headache and cant understand why really the data isnt being saved to my database!!!

adding the urls.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('accounts/register', views.register, name='register'),
    path('accounts/login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name = 'accounts/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='accounts/logout.html'), name='logout'),
    
    
]
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that form is not going to `register` view, kindly check it as the name you have mentioned to redirect is `home` in `href` of input tag (maybe the name is `register` or something else check it), also suggest not to mention anything like `action` or `href` as Django by default take current page route, so:

Template file:

```
  <form method="POST" action="{% url 'register' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}    
        <div class="form-row" >
            <div class="col-md-6 mb-0">
              {{ form.email|as_crispy_field }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 mb-0">
              {{ form.username|as_crispy_field }}
            </div>
            <!--<div class="col-md-6 mb-0">
              {{ form.profile_picture|as_crispy_field }}
            </div>-->
            <div class="col-md-12 mb-0">
              {{ form.address|as_crispy_field }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 mb-0">
              {{ form.phone_number|as_crispy_field }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 mb-0">
              {{ form.car|as_crispy_field }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 mb-0">
              {{ form.details|as_crispy_field }}
            </div>
            <input style="margin-left: 10px;" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Sign Up">

        </div>
    </form>
```

views.py:

```py
def register(request):
    form = "" # for the error -- local variable 'form' referenced before assignment if occurs.
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'User successfully registered!')
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            print('Form is not valid')
            print(form.errors)
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
    return render(request, 'accounts/register.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 0):

RegisterForm doesn't save data because form.is_valid() is False.

for your RegisterForm

as long as you are using file(image) field in your form you should add enctype to your form tag in template, following :

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

also for using ImageField inside your model you should install Pillow library too.
and inside your register view you should instantiate your form like this:

```
form = RegistrationForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

Comment: still does not work out because i tried commenting out the profile_pic field and see if the form will save data..it still does not do so

Comment: @IsalanyaMwaseSam Can you please also share urls.py?

Comment: just print out form.errors and see what's wrong with it

Comment: i have added the urls.py file

Comment: @IsalanyaMwaseSam Add `action="{% url 'register' %}"` in Form, previously you are redirecting it to wrong view which is `home`, try [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73530627/17562044) answer, also you haven't included `profile_picture` fields in forms, so the solution will also work without `enctype="multipart/form-data"` and if you add so kindly include this. Also try to restart server in another port as `python manage.py runserver 5000`  and also hard refresh it through `Ctrl+f5`.

Comment: @hiwa Dear Answerer, it is `enctype` not `entype`  refer [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-enctype) docs, I think its typo ;)

Comment: @IsalanyaMwaseSam Also you are redirecting to that view which has name `home` after successfully saving the form, is it really any view as its not mentioned in urls.py you've shared?

Comment: @sunderam-dubey , yes you're right it's typo, updated it.

Comment: what? sorry i don't recall now!!

Comment: @SunderamDubey..yes, home is a view but its is one of my other apps in my project

Comment: @IsalanyaMwaseSam Have you tried this [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73530627/17562044) answer.

Comment: @SunderamDubey i have..there is an error...but could you help me out on it...looks like its also looking out for a password field which i dont have.........................<ul class="errorlist"><li>password1<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>password2<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>profile_picture<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>